# python3 code not produces error in doctest but working when run without using doctest

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

```
"""
>>> ip_tuple = process("2\t1.001451000\t192.168.0.24\t\t10.0.0.5\t\t98\t84\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1")

"""
import doctest
def process(line):
    list_lines = line.split('\t')
    return (list_lines[2], int(list_lines[7]))

doctest.testmod()
```

When I run it, I would expect it to pass all tests, but the following output is produced:

> ```
> e/lab4/Q9# python3 solution.py
> **********************************************************************
> File "solution.py", line 2, in __main__
> Failed example:
>     ip_tuple = process("2       1.001451000     192.168.0.24            10.0.0.5                98      84
>                                               1")
> Exception raised:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
>         compileflags, 1), test.globs)
>       File "<doctest __main__[0]>", line 1, in <module>
>         ip_tuple = process("2       1.001451000     192.168.0.24            10.0.0.5                98      84
>                                                   1")
>       File "solution.py", line 8, in process
>         return (list_lines[2], int(list_lines[7]))
>     IndexError: list index out of range
> **********************************************************************
> 1 items had failures:
>    1 of   1 in __main__
> ***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
> ```

Strangely when I get rid of the docstring and run the same code with the test, producing the following file:

```
def process(line):
    list_lines = line.split('\t')
    return (list_lines[2], int(list_lines[7]))

ip_tuple = process("2\t1.001451000\t192.168.0.24\t\t10.0.0.5\t\t98\t84\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1")
print(ip_tuple)
```

No error is produced and the following output is printed:

```
('192.168.0.24', 84)
```

Please explain why this is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docstring` is provided with the raw string, so all the `\t` are treated as the escaped `\\t`, so in fact, `split('\t')` doesn't really work as you expected.

This can also be confirmed by adding debug prints in the docstring:

```
"""
>>> test_string = "2\t1.001451000\t192.168.0.24\t\t10.0.0.5\t\t98\t84\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1"
>>> print(test_string.split('\t'))
"""
```

Outputs

```
['2', ' 1.001451000     192.168.0.24', '     10.0.0.5', '', '  98      84', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '      1']
```

Escaping the `\t` in the docstring works:

```
import doctest

def process(line):
    """
    >>> ip_tuple = process("2\\t1.001451000\\t192.168.0.24\\t\\t10.0.0.5\\t\\t98\\t84\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t1")
    """
    list_lines = line.split('\t')
    return (list_lines[2], int(list_lines[7]))


doctest.testmod()
```

passes with no errors.

**EDIT**

Making the entire docstring a raw string also fixes the problem.

```
import doctest

def process(line):
#   V note the r for raw string
    r"""
    >>> ip_tuple = process("2\t1.001451000\t192.168.0.24\t\t10.0.0.5\t\t98\t84\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1")
    """
    list_lines = line.split('\t')
    return (list_lines[2], int(list_lines[7]))

doctest.testmod()
```

passes with no errors.